# Oracle 18c XE cannot be accessed trough web browser due to adobe flash player end of life

Tags: database, oracle, adobe

i installed Oracle 18c XE then i tried to access the EM trough web browser , im using edge and google chrome , didn't work as still adobe flash player is mandatory on windows , I use Sql Developer but still i need to access the Enterprise Manager trough web browser .I couldn't find any help searching , even the installation guide from oracle webpage doesn't say nothing about flash player's end of life after 31 of December 2020. How can i access the EM trough web browser ? Thank you .

Comment: FWIW, I've been working with oracle since v 7.3 - around 1995 - and very rarely have used EM.  And when I did, it was more to explore what it had.  I can't remember the last time I even looked at it.  All  that to explain why I ask why you think you "need" it?  Ask yourself this - what will you do if it turns out there is not solution, and EM simply is not available?  (And THAT said, I would agree that Oracle appears to be derelict in having a "key" product that requires an out-of-support bit of 3d-party infrastructure).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and also for taking your time to replay  , yes it seems we share the same conclusion about Oracle not optimising its product and the installing documentation on its site ,  even after few years notice from adobe regard stopping the support for flash player . i will continue to use Sql developer and Sql+ as usual , i just thought there is a way to have that accessing way available .